# Poor performance in Ubuntu 13.10 with Intel i5 4670K (intel hd 4600)

Tags: graphics, intel

My fresh install of ubuntu 13.10 is not giving me a smooth desktop experience. Every time I minimize windows, I get an animation delay/lag. Showing all open windows results in tearing.

I am using the intel hd graphics 4600. Anyone got ideas? isn't intel graphics the best for Linux?

Comment: Not really an answer, but, IMO gnome and unity can be a bit laggy. I suggest you try kubuntu or xubuntu.

Comment: same result in kubuntu; screen tearing

Comment: Try adding this line to your boot options (in grub) "i915.i915_enable_rc6=1 acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor video=1366x768-24@60" See http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2191109 If it works I will add the information as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Ubuntu and Kubuntu are a bit overkill** for a low powered computer.
**Try Lubuntu or Xubuntu**.

If you still want to use Ubuntu, try disabling it's effects using CCSM.

- First install CCSM by typing in the terminal

  ```
  sudo apt-get install ccsm
  ```
- Launch ccsm

  ```
  ccsm
  ```
- Deselect all effects
  [image]

  Here you can deselect all three options from the effects section.
- close and save.

> Use of CCSM can break your system,use it at your own risk.(though changes I have told are safe).

Comment: low powered? An i5 4670 and 8 gb ram is low powered? Nah that's not the case. thanks anyway

Comment: @user158170 did you try `CCSM`?